# Redirect DLL output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, console

Currently I have an external module which is printing

```
public static bool ReturnSomething(){
    Console.WriteLine("SomeInformation");
    return true;
}
```

I am calling above module from `Powershell` and I want to redirect the `Console` output to some variable `$stdOut` and return value to another variable `$retValue`

```
$retValue = Call.ReturnSomething
```

How do I redirect the `Console` output to another variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @'
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Doer
    {
        public static bool ReturnSomething() {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeInformation");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
'@

$oldOut = [Console]::Out
$newOut = New-Object IO.StringWriter

try
{
    [Console]::SetOut($newOut)
    $retValue = [Test.Doer]::ReturnSomething() 
}

finally
{
    [Console]::SetOut($oldOut)
}

$output = 'Console output from DLL call: ' + $newOut.ToString()


$output
$retValue
```

Comment: Thanks. but it looks too much to redirect the console output. :-/